# How do I change a vertical tree in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

By *Arrange* and *Insert*, I can make a vertical tree.

If I want to make more boxes in the tree, is that possible by the same functionality? Or do I have to insert box by box in the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

Add the boxes and connections in the editor, then select the root of the tree and click Arrange, Layout, Vertical Tree.